# No syntax errors but code not showing the output

Tags: c

I wrote the code for multiple pre-defined functions, however, the output is not showing at all. What should I do?

[Output message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyghG.png)

It should be showing a text for the encrypted and decrypted messages but the output is blank there.

Here's the code:

```
#include "enigma.h"

const char *ROTOR_CONSTANTS[] = {
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", // Identity Rotor (index 0 - and useful for testing):
        "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ",
        "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE",
        "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO",
        "ESOVPZJAYQUIRHXLNFTGKDCMWB",
        "VZBRGITYUPSDNHLXAWMJQOFECK",
        "JPGVOUMFYQBENHZRDKASXLICTW",
        "NZJHGRCXMYSWBOUFAIVLPEKQDT",
        "FKQHTLXOCBJSPDZRAMEWNIUYGV",
};

void String_func(int flag, char in[], char out[]) {
        flag = (flag > 0) ? flag : 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (int i = 0; in[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                out[i+flag] = in[i];
        }

        out[i+flag] = '\0';


}

// This method reads a character string from the keyboard and 
// stores the string in the parameter msg.
// Keyboard input will be entirely uppercase and spaces followed by 
// the enter key.  
// The string msg should contain only uppercase letters spaces and 
// terminated by the '\0' character
// Do not include the \n entered from the keyboard
void Get_Message(char msg[]){
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    while ((ch=getchar()) != '\n') {
            msg[i] = ch;
            ++i;
    }


    msg[i] = '\0';
    return;
}

// This function reads up to 4 characters from the keyboard
// These characters will be only digits 1 through 8. The user
// will press enter when finished entering the digits.
// The rotor string filled in by the function should only contain 
// the digits terminated by the '\0' character. Do not include
// the \n entered by the user. 
// The function returns the number of active rotors.
int Get_Which_Rotors(char which_rotors[]){
     char arr[5];
    scanf("%4s", arr);
    int value = 0;      //stores integer value of which rotor to be called
    int i = 0;
    while (arr[i] != '\0') {
            if (arr[i] != ' ')
                    value++;
            i++;
    }
    String_func(0, arr, which_rotors);
    return value;
} 

// This function reads an integer from the keyboard and returns it 
// This number represents the number of rotations to apply to the 
// encryption rotors.  The input will be between 0 and 25 inclusive
int Get_Rotations(){
    int rot;        //rotations
        scanf("%d", &rot);
        return rot;
}


// This function copies the rotors indicated in the which_rotors string 
// into the encryption_rotors.  For example if which rotors contains the string 
// {'3', '1', '\0'} Then this function copies the third and first rotors into the 
// encryption rotors array in positions 0 and 1.  
// encryptions_rotors[0] = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO"
// encryptions_rotors[1] = "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ"
void Set_Up_Rotors(char encryption_rotors[4][27], char which_rotors[5]){
    int i, enc = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (which_rotors[i] != '\0') {
            if (which_rotors[i] != ' ') {
                    String_func(0, ROTOR_CONSTANTS[int(which_rotors[i])], encryption_rotors[enc++]);
            }
            i++;
    }

    if (i < 3) {
            int j = i;
            while (j <= 3) {
                    encryption_rotors[j][0] = '\0';
                    ++j;
            }
    }
    return;
}


// This function rotates the characters in each of the active encryption rotors
// to the right by rotations.  For example if rotations is 3 encryption_rotors[0]
// contains "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO" then after rotation this row will contain
// SQOBDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMU.  Apply the same rotation to all for strings in 
// encryption_rotors
void Apply_Rotation(int rotations, char encryption_rotors[4][27]) {
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char rot[rotations+1];
    char rotator[27+rotations];

    while (encryption_rotors[i][0] != '\0') {
            int j = 26-rotations;
            while (j < 26) {
                    rot[index++] = encryption_rotors[i][j];
                    ++j;
            }
            rot[index] = '\0';
            String_func(rotations, encryption_rotors[i], rotator);
            int k = 0;
            while (j < rotations) {
                    rotator[k] = rot[k];
                    ++k;
            }
            rotator[26] = '\0';
            String_func(0, rotator, encryption_rotors[i]);
            index = 0;
            ++i;
    }
    return;
}

// This function takes a string msg and applys the enigma machine to encrypt the message
// The encrypted message is stored in the string encryped_msg 
// Do not change spaces, make sure your encryped_msg is a \0 terminated string
void Encrypt(char encryption_rotors[4][27], int num_active_rotors, char msg[], char encrypted_msg[]){
    String_func(0, msg, encrypted_msg);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < num_active_rotors) {
            int j = 0;
            while (encrypted_msg[j] != '\0') {
                    if (encrypted_msg[j] == ' ')
                            continue;
                    int index = encrypted_msg[j] - 65;
                    encrypted_msg[j] = encryption_rotors[i][index];
                    ++j;
            }
            ++i;
    }
    return;
}


// This function takes a string msg and applys the enigma machine to decrypt the message
// The encrypted message is stored in the string encryped_msg and the decrypted_message
// is returned as a call by reference variable
// remember the encryption rotors must be used in the reverse order to decrypt a message
// Do not change spaces, make sure your decrytped_msg is a \0 terminated string
void Decrypt(char encryption_rotors[4][27], int num_active_rotors, char encrypted_msg[], char decrypted_msg[]) {
     String_func(0, encrypted_msg, decrypted_msg);
     int i = num_active_rotors - 1;
     while (i >= 0) {
        int j = 0;
        while (decrypted_msg[j] != '\0') {
                if(decrypted_msg[j] == ' ')
                        continue;
                int whichIndex = LookForIndex(decrypted_msg[j], encryption_rotors[i]);
                decrypted_msg[j] = ROTOR_CONSTANTS[0][whichIndex];
                ++j;
        }
        --i;
     }
}
```

And the code for the driver is this:

```
#include "enigma.h"

int main() {
    char message[80];
    char encrypted_message[80];
    char decrypted_message[80];
    char which_rotors[5];
    char encryption_rotors[4][27];
    int rotations;
    int num_active_rotors;

    printf("Enter the message to be encrypted or decrypted: ");
    Get_Message(message);

    printf("\nWhich rotors will be used to encrypt the message: ");
    num_active_rotors = Get_Which_Rotors(which_rotors); 

    printf("\nEnter the number of rotations to apply to the encryption rotors: ");
    rotations = Get_Rotations();

    Set_Up_Rotors(encryption_rotors, which_rotors);
    Apply_Rotation(rotations, encryption_rotors);
    Encrypt(encryption_rotors, num_active_rotors, message, encrypted_message);
    Decrypt(encryption_rotors, num_active_rotors, encrypted_message, decrypted_message);

    printf("The encrypted message is: %s", encrypted_message);
    printf("The decrypted message is: %s", decrypted_message);

    return 0;
}
```

Do I edit the enigma_driver.c? I am really unsure what is going on as c is very new to me and it took a lot of time to write this project.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; in[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            out[i+flag] = in[i];
    }

    out[i+flag] = '\0';
```

You have two variables called `i`. The one declared in the `for` statement is the one that gets incremented. So when you execute the last line, `i` is always zero.

Comment: Right, thanks! I changed it but now it shows me: ```command terminated``` after I enter 5.